# How to mail merge last row only

Tags: excel, vba

I have a couple of excels I am messing around with practicing VBA. They all at have code to mail merge. On one excel I subtract the row number from the row where my headers are. For example my headers are on row 22 and my data starts at row 23. So I subtract 22 from the row number and it begins the mail merge from there (or it only starts to count records from there. I am unsure). So if I have 3 rows of data that would be row 23 to 25. The code subtracts 22 and I am left with 3 records to mail merge. I am learning VBA so I have a hard time figuring out the code I need to only do the last row. Here is my mail merge code:

```
Private intakeForm As String
Private wdApp As Word.Application
Public newFilePath As String
Public newFolderName As String

Sub MailMergeAutomation()

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Forms" & "\"

    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim TargetDoc As Word.Document
    Dim recordNumber As Long
    Dim selRow As Range

    Set selRow = Selection

    intakeForm = "New Intake Form"
    recordNumber = selRow.Row
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
        If wdApp Is Nothing Then
            Set wdApp = New Word.Application
        End If
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    With wdApp
        .Visible = False
        Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(filePath & intakeForm)

        wdDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        wdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
        Name:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        Revert:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";Mode=Read", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Headers]"

        With wdDoc.MailMerge
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = recordNumber - 22
                .LastRecord = recordNumber - 22
                '.ActiveRecord = .Ac
                .LastRecord = recordNumber - 22
            End With
            .Execute Pause:=False

            wdApp.Visible = False

            Set TargetDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
            TargetDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Cells(recordNumber, 3) & " " & "- intakeForm.docx"
            wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With

    End With
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How about if you select only the last row e.g. `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Headers] ORDER BY [ID] DESC`?

Comment: @KostasK I don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate a little more? I was thinking of maybe adding a drop down box in the user form or using a column where I can place an "x" in there and then filter utilizing the WHERE which I figured out after posting but it doesn't help me. What does TOP 1, ORDER BY, DESC mean? I'm learning and I'm having trouble tracking.

Comment: `TOP 1` selects only the first row, `TOP 2` selects the first two rows etc. Since we sort our dataset from last to first by calling `ORDER BY [ID] DESC`, it will select the last row. To achieve this, our dataset must contain an ID field e.g. 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: `ORDER BY [ID] ASC` will sort 1,2,3,4,5 and `ORDER BY [ID] DESC` will sort 5,4,3,2,1.

Comment: @KostasK. Interesting, I will try that out. Just to clarify, the ID field 1,2,3,4,5. Is that a column header I need to add or does that mean the vba will sort the records out in ASC or DESC order without the column header? I think because it is in brackets it probably is column header but just want to double check. If it is, I assume I need to figure out how to add the numbers in automatically when my userform writes values to the worksheet.

Comment: It doesnt sort automatically the above scenario, we need to instruct it to do so. Usually an ID field is involved because it contains unique numbers. Sorting by number is faster than sorting by text or date for example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and simplest way to get the last row is usually something like `sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` and should help you.  There are a few other ways of doing it too, so for the record - [5 Different Ways to Find The Last Row or Last Column Using VBA](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba)

Comment: I was looking on how to mail merge just the last row not how to find the last row. I have tried a couple of different ways. `Doing i = (last row code here)' then '.FirstRecord = i'  but can't figure out how to just mail merge last row.